# How to ensure RXJava Observable instructions are executed within the scope of a thread?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm currently using RXJava in combination with database transactions. These database transactions are not thread safe and thus it is mandatory to execute all operations within the scope of a single thread.

One solution would be to convert the Observable into a blocking observable and call the single or last method. This way all observable instructions are executed (if not otherwise specified) within the same thread. The try-with-resources statement will call close once all instructions have been processed.

`try (Trx tx = db.trx()) {
  obs.toBlocking().single();
}`

Alternatively a scheduler could be used to:

1. bind the observable instructions to a certain thread
2. close the transaction once onCompleted is being invoked.

Are there maybe any other alternatives that could be used to ensure that observable instructions are executed within the scope of a single thread?

Comment: have you looked at [the `using` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/using.html)? combined with schedulers/observeOn this could do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Given your sample code, I assume you're accessing the database in observable side effects (e.g. `doOnNext`), and not in subscribe calls, not sure if this is on purpose or not, but you'd better rely on subscribe code for side effects (for writes) or observable sources that you'd merge (for reads).

Note that `toBlocking().single()` doesn't guarantee your observable side effects will happen in the current thread, but only that they have all terminated.

A simpler approach (for writes) is probably to do this:

```
obs.toList().subscribe(list -> 
    try (Trx tx = db.trx()) {
        // do DB stuff foreach item in list
    })
```

(if your observable doesn't terminate, using `buffer` instead of `toList` will do fine)

If you deal with JDBC, you can also have a look at [rxjava-jdbc](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc). Actually even if you don't, the library syntax can give you hints on how to glue DB transactions with Rx.

Comment: Could you explain why you suggest writes should be in subscribe and reads as Observable sources please.

Comment: DB reads are often asynchronous in nature (like an HTTP GET), and are better modeled in Rx as a stream rather than a blocking call in a do statement.

Comment: The point regarding DB writes can be more questionable, but [introtorx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/09_SideEffects.html#SideEffects) explains it somehow. Streams are easier to reason about when they've got no side-effects, e.g. it sometimes makes you subscribe a noop observer to a stream for the sole sake of its side effects.